# Characterization of Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: lebesgue-measure

In L. Simon's book ["Introduction to Geometric Measure Theory"](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf), one can find the following characterization of the Lebesgue outer measure (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) on page 11:

> It is the unique outer measure $\mathcal{L}^n$ such that
>
> 1. $\mathcal{L}^n\left( \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i, b_i) \right) = \prod_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)$ for all open boxes;
> 2. for all subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $\mathcal{L}^n(A) = \inf \left\{ \mathcal{L}^n(U) : A \subset U \text{ and } U \text{ open} \right\}$.

I have trouble proving this statement. The difficulty is that this characterization makes no explicit assumption that $\mathcal{L}^n$ be a Borel regular outer measure. Instead, one needs to prove that open sets are measurable (in the sense of Carathéodory), as a consequence of properties 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$, and let $m$ be another outer measure that satisfies properties (1) and (2).

**Step 1.**  For any product of half-open intervals  $B_1=\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i)$, we have  $ \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i  ,b_i) \subset B_1 \subset \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-\epsilon ,b_i)  $
for all $\epsilon>0$, so  $m(B_1)=L(B_1)$ by monotonicity.

**Step 2.** Let $U$ be a  bounded open set, so that $U \subset Q$ for some half-open dyadic cube $Q$.
Let $E$ be a finite union of  half-open  dyadic cubes    contained in  $U$. Then $m(E) \le L(E)$ by subadditivity, and similarly, $m(Q\setminus E) \le L(Q\setminus E)$, as  $Q\setminus E$ is also a finite union of  half-open  dyadic cubes.  Since $$L(Q)=m(Q) \le m(E)+m(Q\setminus E) \le L(E)+L(Q\setminus E) =L(Q) \,,$$
we deduce that $m(E)=L(E)$.

**Step 3.**  Let $U,Q$ be as in step 2. Let $E_k=E_k(U)$ be the union of all half-open dyadic cubes of side $1/2^k$ contained in  $U$. Then $$U=E_0 \cup \Bigl(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (E_k \setminus E_{k-1})\Bigr) \,.$$
Subadditivity implies that $$m(U) \le  m(E_0)+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k \setminus E_{k-1})  \,,$$
so (using this for the upper bound and monotonicity for the lower bound)
$$m(U)=\lim_k m(E_k)=\lim_k L(E_k)=L(U)\,.$$

**Step 4.** If $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded, then step 3 and property 2 imply that $m(A)=L(A)$.

**Step 5.** Given any $A \subset \mathbb R^n$, write $A_j=A \cap [-j,j]^n$.
Then $$m(A) \le  m(A_1)+ \sum_{j=2 }^\infty m(A_j \setminus A_{j-1})  \,,$$
so (using this for the upper bound and monotonicity for the lower bound)
$$m(A) =\lim_j m(A_j)=\lim_j L(A_j)=L(A) \,.$$